# PHP Get multiple values from database in multiple select options selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the multiple selected values in multiple select options from database. I am getting the result but its repeating in multiple select box. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.
Here is my Code :

```
<?php

    $query = "select pf_no,name from programmer order by name";
    $results=mysqli_query($con, $query); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>=0) 
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            $main_query="select p.name from programmer p,transaction t  where p.pf_no = t.pf_id  and t.owner = '0' and t.project_id = '$pr_id' group by p.name";
            $main_results=mysqli_query($con, $main_query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($main_results)>=0) 
            {
                while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($main_results))
                {
?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['pf_no']; ?>"<?php if($row1['name']==$row['name']) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
<?php

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you display your query output and HTML output if possible, it's bit confusing

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your database, expected result and what do you actually get?

Comment: @M.Hemant my first query will show all names like from A,B,C upto Z. From second query, I am getting few already entered values like B and C. Now when multiple select box will appear, it will show all the values from A to Z but B and C will appear as selected values. In my case, A to Z list got repeated twice. When B was selected in first list and C was selected in second list. I want single list from A to Z and got B and C selected.

Comment: @Atul can you show us both while loops individual result set in array?